# Preserve scroll position when upvoting comments in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, android-app, comment-voting

If I click a comment then click to upvote it, the screen reloads and I'm back at the top of the question.

I think it would be better if it left me where was (with the screen updated of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, it's fixed in the next build.